# JavaScript function naming issue Opera vs. IE11 "start()"

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble with this line of code in my `HTML`:

```
<input type="button" class="someClass" id="myId" onclick="start()" value="Begin">
```

In *Opera 17* everything works fine, in *Internet Explorer 11* I need to rename the `onclick function` to:

```
... onclick="startX()" ...
```

or some other name, but I'm not allowed to use `start()`, why is this so ? And what does the `function start()` do in `IE11` ?

Comment: Why you want to do that ?

Comment: What happens when you use `start()`? Is there an error message? IE11 does not define a global `start()` function (checked with the console) and the only `start()` method it implements applies to the `<marquee>` element.

Comment: Created a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7bBup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frédéric Hamidi I did some research about the  element and I can confirm that the method .start() and also .stop() belongs to it.

Source: [marquee tutorial](http://way2tutorial.com/html/html_marquee_start_stop.php)

PS: the  element is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Windows has confusion with certain historic baggage it carries from DOS days. For example you cannot name a file/folder as `con` is a reserved device name from the DOS era. On the same lines, `start` is a DOS batch scripting command. I believe that is the reason why IE does not like Javascript function named `start`.

Comment: I don't think DOM methods and scripting commands are related enough for your answer to be plausible. In passing, `start` is not actually a DOS command, it was introduced in Windows 95.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would appreciate if you can throw some light on the reason for IE causing problems with a JS function named `start`. Else my answer stays as the best answer!